# Control width of ButtonBox in GTK3

Tags: button, gtk3, pygobject

How to set the width of a Gtk.ButtonBox with horizontal orientation? The width does not react to anything I tried (see code below). This is just a scratchpad example, so please ignore the poor coding. I am just interested how to adjust the width of the ButtonBox.

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class LabelWindow(Gtk.Window):
    style_very_small = Gtk.CssProvider.new()
    style_very_small.load_from_data(
        b''' * { border-width: 0 0 0 0;
                font-size: xx-small;
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
                padding: 0 0 0 0;
                min-width: 0;
                min-height: 0;} ''')


    def __init__(self):
       Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Label Example")
       self.set_default_size(1600, 1000)
       self.get_style_context().add_provider(self.style_very_small, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

       layout = Gtk.Layout()
       layout.set_size(1600, 1000)
       hbutton_box = Gtk.ButtonBox.new(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
       button1 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("He1")
       button2 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("He2")
       hbutton_box.add(button1)
       hbutton_box.add(button2)
       hbutton_box.set_size_request(1, 1)
       button2.set_size_request(1, 1)
       button1.set_size_request(1, 1)
       layout.put(hbutton_box, 200, 200)


       self.add(layout)


window = LabelWindow()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question, what are you trying to achieve exactly? Have the window as small as the 2 buttons?

Comment: If you post some code that actually runs I'll try to help, but this sample is just awful